# get user laravel api axios

Tags: php, laravel, axios

i created laravel cms using vue and axios.

i want get current user that sending post requests

so i followed laravel api documentation and take this structure

```js
// bootstrap.js

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${window.api_token}`;


// vue component file

axios.post('/api/v1/person', this.person)
.then(data => {
            this.$emit('added', data.data);
            this.person.id = data.data.data.id
});
```

```php
// Route in api.php
Route::prefix('v1')->name('api.')->group(function () {

    /**  Person Routes */
    Route::prefix('person')->namespace('Person')->name('person.')->group(function(){
        Route::post('/', 'PersonController@index');

});

});

//in laravel controller i retrun

return response()->json(auth('api')->user());
```

but i get this result
[image]

even i checked console headers and `Authorization` header set properly

[image]

i can get all post data but laravel don`t pass me the user

also i made a repository of this project in github
if you want can follow this link

https://github.com/mohammadZx/crm

Comment: Can you show the route especially where you define the api auth middleware?

Comment: That seems correct, what is you auth guard set to in the config?

Comment: i have didn't nothing change in auth config.

Comment: can you see my github repository?

Answer (score 2):

In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#installation) it states that you have to set the correct guard for Passport to work. Update `auth.php` config.

```
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want use laravel passport

Comment: i can fixed this problem without any package. just in auth.php set some changes

Comment: What are you using then just api tokens?

Comment: It seemed like it helped anyways, please tell me what you changed then i update the answer so we can help others looking at this question :)

Comment: yes. just set ``` 'hash' => false ``` in auth.php

Answer (score -1):

by default, laravel trying to find user by hashing token and for this reason laravel return null because your user api tokens not hashed. so if you change auth.php setting to don't searching hashes api_tokens, this problem will be fixed

```php
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false
    ],
],
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I added some explanation to fix this problem